# How to get Arial Narrow typeface in section header in pdflatex

Tags: fonts, sectioning, koma-script

I am new to LaTeX, so I hope this is not obvious,  but have searched for straightforward documentation on how to do this and can't find it.

I am creating a chapter for a book that has very specific formatting:

- The normal paragraph must be in 10pt Bookman old Style
- The chapter title must be 20pt Verdana bold without a chapter number.
- The section header must be 12 pt Arial Narrow Small-Caps with
  6pts extra space above, and no extra space below.
- The subsection header must be 10Pt Bookman Old Style Bold Italic, 
  no extra space above or below

I am using `pdflatex` to produce the PDF output, and `scrbook` class:

```
\documentclass[11pt,executivepaper,headsepline,footsepline]{scrbook}

%Eliminate the chapter numbers from section numbering
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}

\voffset=0in
\topmargin = 0in
\headheight = 12pt
\headsep = 25pt
\textheight = 8.5in
\footskip = 30pt

\hoffset=0in
\marginparwidth = 0pt
\marginparsep = 0pt
\textwidth = 5.25in
\oddsidemargin = 0pt
\marginparpush = 0pt

\begin{document}
```

I found that there is a command for setting the font of a element:  `\setkomafont{element}{commands}` but I have not figured out how to specify Arial Narrow typface.  The [KOMA -Script bundle documentation](http://web.mit.edu/texsrc/source/latex/koma-script/scrguien.pdf) says 'just about any command will work' which is not really helping me at this moment.

Is there a way to get the desired typfaces in use for my section headers in `scrbook` with `pdflatex`?

Comment: Welcome to the hardest part in my opinion when learning LaTeX: the fonts.

Comment: There is a LaTeX support for Arial, but not for Arial Narrow, nor an URW clone. So if you want to use it you have to use `fontspec` and compile with `Xe/LuaLaTeX`.

Comment: Or install the fonts yourself... but you don't want to do that ;(.

Comment: OK, I tried XeLaTeX, and I got one error, but it seems to produce a PDF that looks the same as that from pdflatex.   I will try some experimentation with fontspec later tonight.

Comment: @cfr, I did that once time. So my opinion on hardest part... lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer appears to be: don't do it with `pdflatex`. Thanks to Bernard, cfr, and Sigur and I was able to find a solution which I can share.

You can import and use named fonts using the `fontspec` package.  This package does not work with `pdflatex`.  I had to switch to `xelatex`.  Initial tests showed that `xelatex` would compile my existing document with only one small error that could be easily fixed.

Here is the commands to import and use those fonts

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\fontspec{Bookman Old Style}
\fontspec{Arial Narrow}
\fontspec{Verdana}
\setmainfont{Bookman Old Style}

\setkomafont{section}{\fontspec{Arial Narrow}\fontsize{12}{15}\scshape}
\setkomafont{subsection}{\fontspec{Bookman Old Style}\bfseries\slshape}
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\fontspec{Arial Narrow}\footnotesize\scshape}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}{\fontspec{Verdana}\bfseries
             \fontsize{20pt}{24pt}\centering\selectfont}{}{0em}{}
```

This worked for the most part except for the small caps (`\scshape`) on the section titles.  It seems that LaTeX treats small caps as a font, and requires a separate font for that.  Most word processors simply simulate this by using a regular capital letter at a smaller size.  This would seem like something that LaTeX could do, and maybe it does with the inclusion of yet another obscure package.

Using `\fontsize` I was able to specify the size in points of the various header pieces.  While the documentation is not clear, aparently sometimes you need to use both the `\fontsize` command followed by the `\selectfont` command.  That was the case for the `\titleformat` command.  Without the `\selectfont` the settings would not appear.

Comment: Regarding "exact" (absolute) font sizes, take a look at the `\fontsize{}{}` command.